# Plaid quickstart unable to run backend server using java in sandbox

Tags: java, api, plaid

I am trying to run the backend server using java in sandbox environment. But when I run the command (./start.sh) the shell pop up for once saying [env: '../.env.example/\r' - no such file or directory] and get terminated itself. If someone have come across similar kind of issue and have any solution to it, please help resolve this issue!

- OS: Windows 10
- java jdk 1.8 version
- maven: 3.8.3 version
- dropwizard.version: 1.3.2

[config.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7tES.png)
[start.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvEBM.png)

- .env path: D:\java\ .env
  [.env file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkpte.png)

Comment: Did you create a .env file? If so, can you provide the full path to the .env file in your question? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex. I have provided the path in my question. Hope you can figure out the problem and help me out with this.

Comment: The .env file needs to be in the same directory as the Java quickstart -- if you make sure to follow the instructions here, what happens? https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#setting-up-without-docker

Comment: Please remove code as images and post them within question itself

Comment: I have already solved the problem. Thanks coldy!